# When do I verify the email before creating a subscription with stripe?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification, stripe.js

1. I know stripe doesn't have anything to do with verifying emails.
2. I have a form on my website where I collect a new user's email, password and cc info.
3. As of now I do not verfiy the user's email.  I simply create the user in my system and create the strip user and subscription after I get the card token with stripe.js.
4. I want to verify the email address, but I am not sure at what point in the process to do it.  I don't think it makes sense to charge the customer and start the subscription and then verify the email address.

Should I wait and start the stripe subscription when the customer verifies the email address?  It seems like this is one of the most common scenario's online.  Is their a best practice for this scenario?

Again, I am not asking technically how to verify the email address (I use firebase auth), I just want to know when I should and how it should fit into my onboarding flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can after Firebase Auth account creation, check if the `emailVerified` is true. If not, send an email verification and pass a `continueUrl` to continue the subscription process, instructing the user to check their email to continue the subscription process. This is a common process for many subscriptions that require email verification.

You can learn more about passing `continueUrl` via email verifications: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions

You can build your own custom landing page where you continue the subscription using the following instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Make sure you check `email_verified` in the `idToken` after ID token verification to confirm verification, server side.